# не запускается mariadb

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mariadb

пытаюсь поставить mariadb на ubuntu 18.04, после установки пытаюсь запустить командой

> sudo mariadb

на выходе получаю ошибку:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")

подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Запустить **сервер** MariaDB.

Comment: @D-side он же там всегда запущен ! вроде бы

Comment: @МаксимЛенский судя по сообщению об ошибке -- либо нет, либо настройки клиента по умолчанию не позволяют с ним соединиться. А я сомневаюсь, что ТС менял настройки. И что в пакете настройки такие несогласованные тоже сомневаюсь.

Comment: а каким образом вы устанавливали ? какую команду писали в терминал ?

Comment: mariadb -u username -p

Answer (score 4):

> пытаюсь запустить командой
>
> `sudo mariadb`

1. это вообще-то не сервер, а клиент *mysql*. собственно `/usr/bin/mariadb` является символической ссылкой на `/usr/bin/mysql` (по крайней мере в пакете `mariadb-client` из репозитория дистрибутива *ubuntu* версии 18.04)
2. запускать его от имени пользователя `root` в вашем случае не имеет смысла. запускайте от имени пользователя, под которым работаете:

   ```
   $ mysql
   ```

   или

   ```
   $ mariadb
   ```

   если вам больше нравится новое имя.

---

> получаю ошибку:
>
> > ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111 "Connection refused")

сервер не запущен. и нет уверенности, что вы его вообще установили (судя по продемонстрированному недопониманию того, что у mysql/mariadb есть сервер, и есть клиент, и это две совсем разные программы).

если не установили, то поставьте:

```
$ sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

если уже установили, но он не запущен, попробуйте запустить:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

работает ли процесс `mysqld` можно, например, так:

```
$ pgrep -a mysqld
```

если процессов не нашлось, смотрите лог и устраняйте изложенные там проблемы:

```
$ sudo less /var/log/mysql/error.log
```